# Combining file permissions

Tags: python, file, permissions

I want to set executable permissions for a file I have created in python. 
If I do `os.chmod(file, stat.S_IXUSR)`, the existing permissions are overwritten. How do I combine the existing permissions for the file with executable permissions?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`stat` it first.

```
mode = os.stat(filename).st_mode
os.chmod(filename, mode | stat.S_IXUSR)
```

Comment: You have a race  condition here - but probably it cannot be done without one - so +1 :-)

Comment: @glglgl: Could try locking the file, but I don't remember if it prevents mode changes.

Comment: Probably not. I just ran a `strace chmod g+w <file>` as an example, and it dodn't do so as well. So I suppose your answer is absolutely correct.

Comment: If in the time between querying st_mode and `chmod()` another process happens to try to change the mode, its actions get silently swallowed. But if I think again about it, that may happen at any time if actions occur from several processes at once, so I'm probably mistaken.

Answer (score -1):

Probably just with

```
  os.system('chmod %d "%s"' % ("+x", file))
```

should do the trick

Comment: The question is probably it's Python equivalent.

Comment: If you want to run external processes, use `subprocess`, not `os.system`.

Comment: Also, the formatting will fail with this format string and those arguments.

Comment: @Louis and what if my file is an audio book and is named `The Guy Named "Bertie".mp3`?

Comment: Indeed, my quick-and-dirty sample is just a bad solution. I suggest to delete my answer. (I used it years ago in a simple case where all file names had the same simple format "file001", "file002", "file003" ... and tought it may help, but the other answer is obviously the only good one.